# "event" argument in exports.handler of nodejs lambda function triggered by cloudwatch log

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I have an AWS Lambda function written in NodeJS which is triggered by a CloudWatch Subscription filter.  I was told that the "event" argument of exports.handler in the Lambda function is what I use to get the Log data.

When I print that I see the following which looks nothing like the human readable data I see in the actual CloudWatch console.  What does this mean?!?  Here's what I get:

```
{ awslogs: { data: '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' } }
```

According to the following link, this data is not wrong:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/eventsources.html#eventsources-cloudwatch-logs

And according to this answer in StackOverflow, this is data is not wrong either:
[KeyError: 'awslogs' ... outEvent = str(event['awslogs']['data']) - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44959730/keyerror-awslogs-outevent-streventawslogsdata-python/45064456#45064456)

Thanks a lot in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You accurately found a [Amazon CloudWatch Logs Sample Event](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/eventsources.html#eventsources-cloudwatch-logs). So based on this, your `event` object would be structured something like:

```
{
  "awslogs": {
    "data": "H4sIAAAAAAAAAHWPwQqCQBCGX0Xm7EFtK+smZBEUgXoLCdMhFtKV3akI8d0bLYmibvPPN3wz00CJxmQnTO41whwWQRIctmEcB6sQbFC3CjW3XW8kxpOpP+OC22d1Wml1qZkQGtoMsScxaczKN3plG8zlaHIta5KqWsozoTYw3/djzwhpLwivWFGHGpAFe7DL68JlBUk+l7KSN7tCOEJ4M3/qOI49vMHj+zCKdlFqLaU2ZHV2a4Ct/an0/ivdX8oYc1UVX860fQDQiMdxRQEAAA=="
  }
}
```

**What is it?**

Lets unpack this to understand better what is going on here. In this case `event.awslogs.data` would have the value:

```
"H4sIAAAAAAAAAHWPwQqCQBCGX0Xm7EFtK+smZBEUgXoLCdMhFtKV3akI8d0bLYmibvPPN3wz00CJxmQnTO41whwWQRIctmEcB6sQbFC3CjW3XW8kxpOpP+OC22d1Wml1qZkQGtoMsScxaczKN3plG8zlaHIta5KqWsozoTYw3/djzwhpLwivWFGHGpAFe7DL68JlBUk+l7KSN7tCOEJ4M3/qOI49vMHj+zCKdlFqLaU2ZHV2a4Ct/an0/ivdX8oYc1UVX860fQDQiMdxRQEAAA=="
```

This value is actually a **Base64** encoded string of a GZIPPED payload. This is done to compress the payload, and keep it small, while allowing it to be transported in JSON.

If we Base64 decode this, then unzip it, we end up with the following value:

```
{
  "messageType": "DATA_MESSAGE",
  "owner": "123456789123",
  "logGroup": "testLogGroup",
  "logStream": "testLogStream",
  "subscriptionFilters": [
    "testFilter"
  ],
  "logEvents": [
    {
      "id": "eventId1",
      "timestamp": 1440442987000,
      "message": "[ERROR] First test message"
    },
    {
      "id": "eventId2",
      "timestamp": 1440442987001,
      "message": "[ERROR] Second test message"
    }
  ]
}
```

The elements of this are the following:

- `messageType`: Either be `DATA_MESSAGE` or `CONTROL_MESSAGE`, where if my understanding is right, `CONTROL_MESSAGE` is used for checking for the reachability of your lambda
- `owner`: The AWS Account ID of the originating log
- `logGroup`: The Log Group of the originating log
- `logStream`: The Log Stream of the originating log
- `subscriptionFilter`: The matching Subscription Filter Names
- `logEvents`: The actual logs related to what you see in the Console

**How do I use it?**

You can easily achieve something similar in your Node.js Lambda using the following example from CloudWatches [Subscription Filters with AWS Lambda](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/SubscriptionFilters.html#LambdaFunctionExample):

```
var zlib = require('zlib');
exports.handler = function(input, context) {
    var payload = new Buffer(input.awslogs.data, 'base64');
    zlib.gunzip(payload, function(e, result) {
        if (e) { 
            context.fail(e);
        } else {
            result = JSON.parse(result.toString('ascii'));
            console.log("Event Data:", JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
            context.succeed();
        }
    });
};
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

> What does this mean?!?

When you see strings made up of only the characters `[A-Z][a-z][0-9][+/=]`, that's usually an indication of Base64 encoding.  Base64 allows transports that do not support arbitrary binary data... to carry arbitrary binary data, by re-encoding it using a format that conveys only 6 (instead of 8) bits per byte, using 64 (2^6) symbols, all of which are standard ASCII characters and thus compatible with text transport.

Why would the data be binary?

Because it's gzipped.  Gzip is a compression algorithm that is pretty good and very fast at compressing text... but Gzipping text produces arbitrary binary data, so it can't be serialized in JSON, which only supports text (and numbers and true/false/null).

So, the gzipped data is encoded in base64 for transport inside JSON.

You need to convert the base64 representation to binary, and g-un-zip it.

Example from http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/SubscriptionFilters.html#LambdaFunctionExample:

```
var zlib = require('zlib');
exports.handler = function(input, context) {
    var payload = new Buffer(input.awslogs.data, 'base64'); // decode base64 to binary
    zlib.gunzip(payload, function(e, result) { // gunzip the binary data
        if (e) { 
            context.fail(e);
        } else {
            result = JSON.parse(result.toString('ascii'));
            console.log("Event Data:", JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
            context.succeed();
        }
    });
};
```

Note that this uses the old `context.fail()` and `context.succeed()` convention, which is apparently still supported for backward compatibility, but shouldn't be used in new code.  See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-using-old-runtime.html#nodejs-prog-model-oldruntime-context-methods.